# There is not enough space on davwwwroot when pasting

Tags: explorer-view

I am trying to paste 5GB into a library through the Explorer View
Unfortunately, I get this message:

> There is not enough space on davwwwroot. You need an additional 2,06
>   to copy the files.

I am using SharePoint 2013. 
I have already tried the following:

- I have checked that I have enough space on both the Sql Server and
  Front End machine. Limit site storage in Central Administration  is
  not checked Increased requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength to
  "6147483647"

What  else could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking the uploads into smaller chunks. You are probably breaching one of the SharePoint limits by trying to transfer 5GB of files in one go so whilst you may have plenty of space to store 5GB of files, you cannot dump them on the server in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

Explorer View uses WebDAV--via the **WebClient** service running on your local computer--to transfer files between your local filesystem and SharePoint libraries.

The WebClient service itself imposes a size limit (around 50 MB) to the amount of content it can move, regardless of the file size limits SharePoint sets on the server side. **This limit is determined by a registry setting on your PC.**

If you're confident enough to modify your registry settings (I encourage you to back up your registry before changing anything) you can try [these steps from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2668751):

> To solve this Problem customize the following Registry Entry:
>
> 1.Click Start, type regedit in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.
>
> 2.Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters
>
> 3.locate the DWORD FileSizeLimitInBytes
>
> 4.On the Edit menu, click Modify.
>
> 5.In the Value data box increase the Value of 50000000 (in bytes)
>
> 6.Exit Registry Editor.
>
> 7.Restart the Web Client Service

Comment: Probably that size limit refers to a single file. My problem was that all files together where over than 2GB